# AWS Cloud9上でのRailsアプリケーションにて、$ rails serverにてローカルサーバーを立ち上げ後にページを確認しても変更が反映されていない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-cloud9

現在Ruby on Railsチュートリアルを推奨環境のAWS Cloud9上にて取り組んでおります。

[第3章 3.2 静的ページ 3.2.1 静的なページの生成](https://railstutorial.jp/chapters/static_pages?version=6.0#sec-generated_static_pages)の項目で`$ rails generate controller StaticPages home help`を実行し、コミット&プッシュ後に`$ rails server`のコマンドにてローカルサーバーを立ち上げ、ページを確認しても、直前の[3.1 セットアップ](https://railstutorial.jp/chapters/static_pages?version=6.0#sec-sample_app_setup)の項目で行った`hello, world!`のみが表示されるページしか表示されません。

[image: 表示されるページ]

ターミナル上ではエラーも表示されておらず、検索してもなかなかこれといったものがヒットせず、Cloud9の再起動やCloud9のインスタンスを削除し、再度イチから構成し直して実施しても同様の状態になり、どうすればよいのか検討もつかない状態です。

GitHubのリポジトリは[こちら](https://github.com/Kawboy442/sample_app/tree/097f816391951a87eda3206aa065df4ab4af6951)になります。

どなたかご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: ページの確認はどのように行われましたか？　具体的には、どの URL にアクセスなさいましたか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。URLについてはAWS Cloud9上のローカルサーバーを立ち上げ、カリキュラム通り[```/static_pages/home```](https://384d55480502424984e41c041328a944.vfs.cloud9.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ap-northeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/static_pages/home)もしくは[```/static_pages/help```](https://384d55480502424984e41c041328a944.vfs.cloud9.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ap-northeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/static_pages/help)にアクセスしております。どちらにアクセスしても質問で添付している画像のようなページの表示になってしまいます。

Comment: /static_pages/home にアクセスしても view の erb ファイルで指定している内容でも 404 Not Found でもなく root に指定している内容が表示されるのは何かアクセスの仕方がおかしそうな予感がしています。

Answer (score 1):

static_pagesに対するルーティングの設定がないのが原因かと思います。

https://github.com/Kawboy442/sample_app/blob/c7dbc6bb9b5897882df5f1cbba1ee8f94ea7ba73/config/routes.rb

次のような定義を追加するとどうでしょうか

```rb
get 'static_pages/home', to: 'static_pages#home'
get 'static_pages/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
```

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。ルーティングの設定ですが、記載のURLのブランチでは質問の項目の設定していないのですが、[別ブランチ](https://github.com/Kawboy442/sample_app/blob/static-pages/config/routes.rb)にて設定をしております。また、こちらのブランチにて頂いたコードで該当箇所を置き換えて再起動して確認しましたが、同じ状態のままですね...